# zombie process created in code, and killed in another part

Tags: c, linux, process, zombie-process

I want to write a 'zombie creator' and 'zombie terminator'. Main point is that I want to create zombies in one part and terminate them in other part of code. I'm using C.

Example:

```
create_zombie(); //let's say it's a spawn, using fork etc.

/* a houndred lines below */

kill_zombie(PID); // PID is determinated by user, I want to leave him the choice
```

I know how to do this using fork(), if .. else, but that's not the point. I'm looking for some kind of remote control. Is that possible? Sleeping him for a long time could be a solution?

Comment: By zombie you mean UNIX Zombie process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Linux, but the process should be similar on other operating systems. You want to look into the `kill()` function declared typically declared in the `signal.h` header file. This will allow you to send a signal to a specific PID from your zombie killer. The easiest approach would be to send your zombie process a kill signal (`SIGKILL`). `SIGKILL` cannot be caught or ignored, and immediately kill a process dead.

If you need to do some cleanup in your zombie process, you can create a signal handler with the `signal()` function. This will allow you to specify a function to call when a process receives a signal. This function would implement your cleanup code and then `exit()`.

On linux, your shell should have a kill command that mimics the functionality of `kill()`. The syntax is typically `kill -s 9 PID`. This will send a SIGKILL (signal number 9) to the process PID.

I hope this answer nudges you in the proper direction.

Comment: Yea, signals looks like a good solution. I'll try that.
And yes, linux (look tags)

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed the Linux tag until after I submitted. Hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you fork a process, fork returns 0 in the child process and the child's process id in the parent.  You can save them in an array, write them to a file, or write them to a pipe and don't "uncap" the other end until you need it.

Comment: it has been too long for me to get it right without a compiler handy, but http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo to make a pipe and write to it like a normal fd in the zombie generator ... open it for reading like a normal file in the zombie killer